# Programmatically updating editing interface in Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am working on a Django Wagtail project where I sometimes change Page data in an 'after_edit_page' hook. What I do is set a value for a ForeignKey relation, where that object is a Snippet. When I update a Page field I can see those changes correctly in the live page, so the Model is saved correctly. But when I go to the editing interface I cannot see that same change in the SnippetChooserPanel, which is still empty.

As this is very confusing for Page editors I was wondering how I could programmatically update the editor panels in the admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because a draft of the page is saved to the wagtailcore.PageRevision table after you edit a page. This draft is then used to populate the admin form when you go back to edit the page. The draft is saved before the 'after_page_edit' signal is triggered, so any modifications to the Page will not be included in the PageRevision, hence will not appear the next time you load the admin interface.

Instead, you can override the form used for a Page model, using a (currently undocumented, sorry) feature:

```
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page

class MyPageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyPageForm, self).clean()
        # Set the snippet to a new value
        cleaned_data['snippet'] = MySnippet.objects.get()
        return cleaned_data

class MyPage(Page):
    # Your fields, etc here...

    base_form_class = MyPageForm
```

This functionality does require a recent (1.4.3+) version of Wagtail to work.

Comment: Thanks! I was already looking into the custom form solution, which I saw in the issue tracker on Github. Much appreciated!

Comment: Please note that, since Wagtail 2.0, `wagtail.wagtailadmin.forms` has become `wagtail.admin.forms` and `wagtail.wagtailcore.models` has become `wagtail.core.models`